# Implicit Writer for a sealed trait with subclasses containing the same fields

Tags: scala, play-json

I am trying to build a REST server in Scala Play Framework.
I have built a simple response hierachy, here is the code I have:

```scala
package api

import play.api.libs.json._

sealed trait ApiResponse{
    def responseType: String
    def responseContent: String
    def requestCode: String
}

object ApiResponse{
    implicit val responseWriter = new Writes[ApiResponse] { 
        def writes[A <: ApiResponse](response : A) = Json.obj(
            "responseType" -> response.responseType,
            "responseContent" -> response.responseContent,
            "requestCode" -> response.requestCode
        )
    }
}

case class ErrorResponse(reason: String) extends ApiResponse{
    val responseType = "Error"
    val responseContent = reason
    val requestCode = "None"
}

case class ImageResponse(imageFormat: String, processingTime: String) extends ApiResponse{
    val responseType = "ParsedImage"
    val responseContent = /**TODO**/
    val requestCode = /**TODO**/
}
```

I decided to use subclassing instead of a factory method since the responses might for a reason be mutable. This is of little relevance for the problem though.

The important part is, that all of the subclasses will only be serialised based on the *responseType*, *responseContent* and *requestCode* fields, so from a logical standpoint it is perfectly fine to define a writer for the whole trait, which is what I do in the companion object.

I then use this hierarchy to return for example an error when an invalid API request is made:

```scala
    def error(any: String) = Action { 
        Ok(
            Json.toJson(new ErrorResponse("Invalid API call"))(ApiResponse.responseWriter)
        )
    }
```

But the above line doesn't compile, since the compiler detects that the trait Writer is invariant in A. This is the exact error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : play.api.libs.json.Writes[api.ApiResponse]{def writes[A <: api.ApiResponse](response: A): play.api.libs.json.JsObject}
 required: play.api.libs.json.Writes[api.ErrorResponse]
Note: api.ApiResponse >: api.ErrorResponse (and play.api.libs.json.Writes[api.ApiResponse]{def writes[A <: api.ApiResponse](response: A): play.api.libs.json.JsObject} <: play.api.libs.json.Writes[api.ApiResponse]), but trait Writes is invariant in type A.
You may wish to define A as -A instead. (SLS 4.5)
```

I understand this error that way:

- *api.ApiResponse* is a supertype of *api.ErrorResponse* (which is fine)
- my definiton of the *writes* method is a subtype of the type *json.Writes[api.ApiResponse]* (which I also think is fine),
- but the Writes trait itself is invariant in type A, and this is the part I don't quite understand, but I believe it means that there is no hierachy between the objects of trait Writes, but I believe the definition of the write function should impose such a hierarchy.

So Is there a way to redefine this hierarchy in such a way that it works with minimal code overhead? If not I believe it would just be better to define the same writer for all of the subclasses.

Comment: Having a Writer typeclass with variance is generally a bad idea: https://github.com/playframework/play-json/pull/216

If you want to define a instance of `Writes` with variance, that's up to you `def foo[T <: X]: Writes[T] = ???`

Comment: @cchantep Your solution works, however do You think in this exact case a Writer with variance is also a bad design choice?